# getting attempt to de-reference a null object while assigning value to a list

Tags: apex, soql, list

```
List<SIM_Cam_Request__c> requestRecordList=new List<SIM_Cam_Request__c>();
requestRecordList = [SELECT id, name, SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.Name, deletedSimCamSystemRole__c, FROM xyztable WHERE Id=: childRequestId]; 

 if(requestRecordList[0].SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.name=='' || requestRecordList[0].SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.name==null)
{
requestRecordList[0].SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.name=requestRecordList[0].deletedSimCamSystemRole__c;
}
```

I know **SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.name** is a lookup field but since its in array I can replace the value of index but it is throws error attempt to de-reference a null object. I hv also initialized the list

---

Is it possible without inserting a record bcoz that record is deleted and I hv written a before delete trigger so whenever SIM_Cam_Request__c record is deleted it will store the value of SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.Name in deletedSimCamSystemRole__c and once record is deleted I can reassign the value. I'm displaying SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.Name value on UI. If it's not possible without inserting then I'll make change in lwc:js file. BTW thanx for response

Answer (score 1):

The initialization doesn't matter, because you're immediately overwriting it with a query. It'd be more efficient to just write:

```
List<SIM_Cam_Request__c> requestRecordList = [
  SELECT id, name, SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.Name, deletedSimCamSystemRole__c 
  FROM xyztable 
  WHERE Id=: childRequestId
];
```

As far as the null pointer exception, you're apparently trying to access `SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.Name` to assign a value, which isn't legal, since `SIM_Cam_System_Role__r` is probably null.

Aside from that, updating a related object isn't possible without having a copy of that object in memory directly, so you'd want to write something like:

```
List<SIM_Cam_Request__c> requestRecordList = [SELECT id, name, SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.Name, deletedSimCamSystemRole__c FROM xyztable WHERE Id=: childRequestId]; 
Map<Id, SIM_Cam_Request__c> values = new Map<Id, SIM_Cam_Request__c>();
if(requestRecordList[0].SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.name=='' || requestRecordList[0].SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.name==null) {
    values.put(
        requestRecordList[0].SIM_Cam_System_Role__c,
        new SIM_Cam_Request__c(Id = requestRecordList[0].SIM_Cam_System_Role__c, Name=requestRecordList[0].deletedSimCamSystemRole__c)
    );
}
```

However, this won't work, because the record doesn't exist. Instead, you'd end up having to create the new records, then associating them back to the record:

```
List<SIM_Cam_Request__c> requestRecordList = [SELECT id, name, SIM_Cam_System_Role__r.Name, deletedSimCamSystemRole__c FROM xyztable WHERE Id=: childRequestId]; 
Map<Id, SIM_Cam_Request__c> values = new Map<Id, SIM_Cam_Request__c>();
if(requestRecordList[0].SIM_Cam_System_Role__c == null) {
    values.put(
        requestRecordList[0].Id,
        new SIM_Cam_Request__c(Name=requestRecordList[0].deletedSimCamSystemRole__c)
    );
}
insert values.values();
for(SIM_Cam_Request__c record: requestRecordList) {
    record.SIM_Cam_System_Role__c = values.get(record.Id);
}
```

You might want to bulkify this code, but the general idea is that you need to perform a DML on the parent record independently in order to create/update the records.

Comment: Referencing cross object fields where the lookup is null does note throw NPE.

Comment: @AdrianLarson For assignments, it does: `Contact c = new Contact();
c.Account.Owner = new User();`

Comment: Ah, fair. Missed that.